# Preg matching a simple mathematical formula causing error

Tags: php, regex, math, preg-match

For some reason while using `preg_match('/^[-+*/^()\s0-9]+$/', $formula` I throw an `Unknown modifier '^'` While trying to run `7 + 6c`, I would be returning false to my knowledge?

Full snippet

```
if (! preg_match('/^[-+*/^()\s0-9]+$/i', $formula )) 
{
    $this->log(array('fatal', $formula, 'Contains unacceptable values...'));
}

$formula = '(7 + 6) / 9'; # 1
$formula = '7 * 6 ^ 2' # 252 
$formula = '1c + 2c' # boom, but no trap =/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your matching criteria, `/^[-+*/^()\s0-9]+$/i`, you'd be running in to an error because `^` is a reserved character meaning the beginning of a set. So you match for it in a regular expression, you'd need to escape it. ie. `/^[-+*/\^()\s0-9]+$/i` However, `-+*` are also reserved and have special meaning even within sets, so those would need to be escaped as well. `/^[\-\+\*\/\^()\s0-9]+$/i`

Ok, based on comments, yes, you are correct, only the delimiter needs to be escaped.  Escaping the rest won't hurt the expression either though, so the answer does still work. The expression that is minimal and also works is `/^[-+*\/^()\s0-9]+$/i`

Comment: What error exactly are you getting with it? From the error you posted, that should work towards fixing it, but the error steps don't seem to match the code you have shown either.

Comment: I expect if that if the criteria above does not match, an error is logged as above. The fatal error i am getting from your code is `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\\'`

Comment: Accepting and upvoting, I replaced my delimiters from // to ~~

Comment: Ahh.  Yes.  I was just about to provide a PHPFiddle for it.  The other way to do it without replacing delimiters would be to escape the the `/` right before your `\^`.  Sorry, I had missed that when posting my answer. ^^

Comment: Actually the only one of those characters in the character class that needs to be escaped is the first `-`.  `^` only has special meaning (and thus need to be escaped) if it is the first character in a character class. `+`,`*`, and `/` do not have special meaning in the character class and do not need to be escaped). See paragraph 10 of documentation here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php  You would however need to escape the `/` in the character class unless you changed the delimiter.

Comment: @MikeBrant: no, you don't need to escape `-` in a character class if you put it at the begining or at the end. The only character that must be escaped here is the `/` because it is used as delimiter.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are correct, My apologies, and updated the answer.